# Getting the JSON response from a POST request Python

Tags: python, json

I'm currently posting to a sever like so:

```
req = urllib2.Request('http://xxx.xxx.xx.xx/upload/')
req.add_header('Content-Type', 'application/json')
response = urllib2.urlopen(req, json_string)
print(response.getcode())
```

I get a 200 code back however I want to read the JSON the server is sending back. How do I do this? (tying to avoid using the requests library)

Comment: From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.urlopen): getcode() — return the HTTP status code of the response.

Answer (score 0):

I did not get code, because I did not have a url.
Try:

```
req = urllib2.Request('http://xxx.xxx.xx.xx/upload/')
req.add_header('Content-Type', 'application/json')
response = urllib2.urlopen(req, json_string)
print(response.read())
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the actual `json` object from the response not just the `json` serialised string you need to parse the response with the `json` library

```
import json
req = urllib2.Request('http://xxx.xxx.xx.xx/upload/')
req.add_header('Content-Type', 'application/json')
response = urllib2.urlopen(req, json_string)
json_response = json.loads(response.read().decode('ascii'))
```

The encoding may also be `utf-8` depending on what the server sends back yo you.

Alternatively you could use the `requests` library which I find much easier to interact with, you'll need to install it separately though with `pip install requests`

```
import requests, json
response = requests.post('http://xxx.xxx.xx.xx/upload', data={'data': json_string})
if response.ok:
    response_json = response.json()
else:
    print('Something went wrong, server sent code {}'.format(response.status_code))
```

[requests library docs](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/)